Transaction sent with txid in log but no swap happened on Jupiter
I got the quote answer and swap answer and even the signed transaction sent but there's no swap and if i check transaction with solana explorer it says the transaction didnt exists (example of transaction through inspecor - tinyurl.com/33n6xmv3)

Even I am facing the same issue below is my code ```
async def sol_transaction(private_key, token_address, public_key, sol_amount): sol_amount = float(sol_amount) client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com") sender = Keypair.from_base58_string(private_key) # Check wallet balance current_balance = get_wallet_balance(private_key) print("Current balance:", current_balance) # Quote API call url = 'https://quote-api.jup.ag/v6/quote' params = { 'inputMint': 'So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112', 'outputMint': token_address, 'amount': str(int(sol_amount * 10**9)) # 'slippageBps': '5

Your transaction has an invalid signature for Ekxy9gmXZ17rpEfdg2s5GtpSrmQrAtmDUWoQw8o4Xg4j: Explorer link
The reason the simulate in Explorer shows success is because it doesn't validate the signatures.
If you look at the payload of the simulateTransaction RPC call you'll see this:
{
    "method": "simulateTransaction",
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "params": [
        "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",
        {
            "accounts": {
                "addresses": [
                    "Ekxy9gmXZ17rpEfdg2s5GtpSrmQrAtmDUWoQw8o4Xg4j",
                    "4kYqawUVbu9kStQJY5JfxqE2v1KHdSYfJZ2zi1gNLd5T",
                    "8tPidwSMgeXDoHC4ncRLHsSS1HGr9cJF8b3g3aVR3dVA",
                    "11111111111111111111111111111111",
                    "ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111",
                    "JUP6LkbZbjS1jKKwapdHNy74zcZ3tLUZoi5QNyVTaV4",
                    "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA",
                    "ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL",
                    "D8cy77BBepLMngZx6ZukaTff5hCt1HrWyKk3Hnd9oitf",
                    "DGSLZCAjafkMqoJViLd57ERfqjVE8ZGSis9xa4GMmNCc"
                ],
                "encoding": "base64"
            },
            "replaceRecentBlockhash": true,
            "encoding": "base64",
            "commitment": "confirmed"
        }
    ],
    "id": "31beba7c-157d-4e9a-8e0d-e2b6370ea937"
}

Notice it includes "replaceRecentBlockhash":true. This means that sigVerify is false, because these options are incompatible (see RPC docs). If you swap that to "sigVerify": true and send the request to a mainnet RPC, you'll get an error from your invalid signature:
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "error": {
        "code": -32003,
        "message": "Transaction signature verification failure"
    },
    "id": "31beba7c-157d-4e9a-8e0d-e2b6370ea937"
}


thanks, i'll try to check why my signature is invalid...

Thank you a lot! I fixed my problem and it works now :)

Double check your RPC. Are you on mainnet?
You can also double check your calls with the Jup API docs
https://api.jup.ag
If you want to provide the Transaction ID, I can have a look what happened.
You can also use Solana Transaction Inspector
https://explorer.solana.com/tx/inspector

I used inspector to check encoded tx and see that signature validity is: "Invalid".
But if I run simulation on the inspector it has Program returned success on all programs

https://tinyurl.com/33n6xmv3
